# Typing function object property

Tags: python, type-hinting, pyright

I have to implement a protocol which sends a message, and gets a response in turn. Usually, the response is instant but in some cases the message sets the device into the correct state to process other messages, and only after processing the other messages will the device respond to the initial message setting the state.

Since the actual code of generating a message based on parameters, and constructing a response object is quite repetitive, I use a decorator to do so. While for 90% of the cases the user wants to `sendMessageX() -> ResponseToMessageX`, there are cases where the user has to `dispatchMessageX() -> Future<ResponseToMessageX>`. Since both functions take the same parameters and essentially return the same thing (`ResponsToMessageX`, at least after resolving the future), it makes sense to generate both functions from the decorator.

The easiest way to do this for me, was to abuse pythons `everything is an object` and simply add the second function as a property to the function object, i.e.:

```
def decorator(f):
    def decorated_f():
        return f()

    def decorated_f_split():
        return f'()
    
    decorated_f.second_function = decorated_f_split

    return decorated_f
```

(If I can help it I am trying to avoid metaclasses to keep things simple and avoid restrictions).

To make it easy on the user I would like typehinting to still work (so the editor can typehint which properties the response object has).

While I got this to work, pyright still complains, and I cant get rid off the warnings. Here is the MWE of what I came up with:

```python
from functools import wraps
from typing import (
    Any,
    Awaitable,
    Callable,
    Concatenate,
    ParamSpec,
    Protocol,
    TypeVar,
    cast,
)

T = TypeVar("T")
C = TypeVar("C", covariant=True)
P = ParamSpec("P")  # , covariant=True)


class X(Protocol[P, C]):
    def split(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Awaitable[C]:
        ...

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> C:
        ...


def wrap_returntype_awaitable(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]:
    f.__annotations__["return"] = Awaitable[T]

    g = cast(Callable[P, Awaitable[T]], f)
    return g


def decorator(f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], C]) -> X[P, C]:
    class Wrapper:
        # @wrap_returntype_awaitable
        @wraps(wrap_returntype_awaitable(f))
        async def split(self, *args: P.args, **kwds: P.kwargs) -> Awaitable[C]:
            await self.send_command()
            return self.get_response()

        @wraps(f)
        async def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwds: P.kwargs) -> C:
            response_receiver = await Wrapper.split(self, *args, **kwds)
            return await response_receiver

    Wrapper.split.__annotations__["return"] = Awaitable[C]

    return Wrapper()


class A:
    async def send_command(self):
        pass

    async def get_response(self):
        pass

    async def command(self, a: int) -> int:
        await self.send_command()
        return a

    @decorator
    async def x(self, a1: int) -> int:
        ...


async def demo():
    a = A()

    response = await a.x()
    split_command = await a.x.split()
    split_response = await split_command
```

I feel forced to use a class inside the decorator, since I can not tell pytright that I want to assign to a property of the function otherwise (I am not sure how to tell pyright that the object I am returning has a property `split` which I need to set (other than surpressing type warnings on that line)). The issue with this is matching the `self` type, in particular since I usually inherit the `send_command`/`get_response` message from a base type of `class A` (ommitted to keep the MWE simpler).

Pyright complains about the following:

```
p2.py:38:24 - error: Cannot access member "send_command" for type "Wrapper"        
    Member "send_command" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
p2.py:39:25 - error: Cannot access member "get_response" for type "Wrapper"        
    Member "get_response" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
p2.py:48:12 - error: Expression of type "Wrapper" cannot be assigned to return type "X[P@decorator, C@decorator]"
    "Wrapper" is incompatible with protocol "X[P@decorator, C@decorator]"
      Type parameter "P@X" is invariant, but "P@X" is not the same as "P@decorator"
      Type parameter "C@X" is covariant, but "Awaitable[C@decorator]" is not a subtype of "C@decorator"
        Type "Awaitable[C@decorator]" cannot be assigned to type "C@decorator" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
3 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

I already touched on the first to warnings (how should I type self here? coercing it to `Base_A` does not work, (`Base_A` has `send_command`/`get_response`, but my decorator calls these with `A._marker_property`). Furthermore, since I am currently using function and not class decorators, there is no way for me to get to `class A` inside the decorator.

I could try to split the decorator into a function decorator that marks my functions and a class decorator (which would have access to the underlying class), but then I would have pyright complaining about assignment of function properties again.

My bigger issue is with the last two errors:

```
    "Wrapper" is incompatible with protocol "X[P@decorator, C@decorator]"
      Type parameter "P@X" is invariant, but "P@X" is not the same as "P@decorator"
      Type parameter "C@X" is covariant, but "Awaitable[C@decorator]" is not a subtype of "C@decorator"
        Type "Awaitable[C@decorator]" cannot be assigned to type "C@decorator"
```

Why is `P@X` not the same as `P@decorator` (The parameterset should be the same? And I cant have a covariant Parameterset...)
And I thought I had typed it correctly so that `Awaitable[C@decorator]` is expected in the right places, yet the typechecker clearly thinks differently.

---

### (I do not have control over the protocol and cant change its design)

**EDIT**: I was so focused on getting completion/inference to work (i.e. for the example, the editor knows that the functions return `int`/`Awaitable[int]`) that I did not actually test the functionality. The access to self breaks, and methods of the parent object can not be called :/

[image: Inference works]

Comment: I had a play with class decorators (to add an additional method to the class), and was reminded that class decorators are not really supported. The added method itself is not recognized by the IDE, let alone its return type. So that is a no go. I might just type out two separate method stubs and use function decorators. While this conflicts with DRY in the library, it does allow for the convenience users need.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution is not ideal, and adds a few more constraints here is what I came up with (it makes the typechecker happy, and typeinference works):

```
from functools import wraps
from typing import (
    Any,
    Awaitable,
    Callable,
    Concatenate,
    ParamSpec,
    Protocol,
    TypeVar,
    cast,
    runtime_checkable,
)

T = TypeVar("T")
C = TypeVar("C", covariant=True)
C2 = TypeVar("C2")
P = ParamSpec("P")  # , covariant=True)


class Response:
    ...


class Commandable(Protocol):
    async def send_command(self) -> Awaitable[Response]:
        ...


@runtime_checkable
class X(Protocol[P, C]):
    _commandable_parent: Commandable

    async def split(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Awaitable[C]:
        ...

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> C:
        ...


def wrap_returntype_awaitable(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]:
    f.__annotations__["return"] = Awaitable[T]

    g = cast(Callable[P, Awaitable[T]], f)
    return g


def decorator(f: Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], C]) -> X[P, C]:
    class Wrapper(X[P, C2]):  # C2 should be C here, but pyright does not like it
        def __init__(self):
            self._commandable_parent = None  # type: ignore # the class decorator fixes this

        @wraps(wrap_returntype_awaitable(f))
        async def split(
            self, *args: P.args, **kwds: P.kwargs
        ) -> Awaitable[Response]:  # if I use Awaitable[C2] here pyright has issues
            return await self._commandable_parent.send_command()

        @wraps(f)
        async def __call__(
            self, *args: P.args, **kwds: P.kwargs
        ) -> Response:  # C2 and Response are not compatible in the return by pyright
            response_receiver = await Wrapper.split(self, *args, **kwds)
            return await response_receiver

    Wrapper.split.__annotations__["return"] = Awaitable[C]

    return Wrapper()


def fixup_parents(cls):
    initialize_command_parent: list[X] = []

    for attribute_name in dir(cls):
        attribute = getattr(cls, attribute_name)

        if isinstance(attribute, X):
            initialize_command_parent.append(attribute)

    original_init = getattr(cls, "__init__")

    @wraps(original_init)
    def fixed_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        for attribute in initialize_command_parent:
            attribute._commandable_parent = self

    cls.__init__ = fixed_init

    return cls


@fixup_parents
class A:
    async def send_command(self):
        return self.get_response()

    async def get_response(self):
        pass

    async def command(self, a: int) -> int:
        await self.send_command()
        return a

    @decorator
    async def x(self, a1: int) -> int:
        ...


async def demo():
    a = A()

    response = await a.x()
    split_command = await a.x.split()
    split_response = await split_command
    print("done")


import asyncio

asyncio.run(demo())
```

While this works there are several ugly bits:

1. I failed to reuse the TypeVar C for the `Wrapper` class inside the `decorator` function
2. One has to fix up self (by going through the classdecorator `fixup_parents` for the callable classes which replace the methods (I am not aware of a cleaner solution))
3. The return type of the methods of the wrapper is statically assigned, and not using the generics as it should. (I could not convince pyright). While this is hidden due to `@wraps` and the return type of the decorator function it ceratinly is not clean

Any better solutions/solutions to the above problems are welcome. I might even post these in a new question/on the pyright qa site.